# find vector $v$ , $v \in R^4$ that satisfy $Av\neq0$ and $A^2v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&1\\0&-1&1&-2\\2&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
here after row reduction
$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&1\\0&1&-1&2\\0&0&1&2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$
clearly determinant is zero
but how can I find vector $v$ , $v \in R^4$ that satisfy $Av\neq0$ and $A^2v=0$ 
$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{bmatrix}$
so I try to row reduce $A^2$ using gauss elimination
$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&\frac{3}{2}&0\\0&1&\frac{-5}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ 
so $x_3$ and $x_4$ is free variable, but in this question I'm not sure what I need to find and should I find Eigen value first?

Comment: You need to find 1 vector or the general solution?

Comment: @gimusi 1 vector that satisfy $ Av\neq0$ and $A^2v=0$, should I find Eigen value first(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Take a vector in $\ker(A^2)$ in the general form $v=sv_1+tv_2$ then solve for $Av\neq 0 $ to find coefficients $s$ and $t$.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 0\\-2\\0 \end{bmatrix} $ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}$ is this right?? , but why I should find vector in $ker(A^2)$? is it mean I find span in column space of $A^2$?

Comment: take a linear combination of them $$v=t\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 0\\-2\\0 \end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}$$ and take $Av$

Comment: You should find 4 equations in t and s, for example t=s=1 should work and maybe it works for all t,s $\neq$ 0

Comment: okay so here I found null space of reduce row echelon form of $A^2$, I'm not sure what this want $Av\neq0$  , is it mean I need to find vector in column space of A?  , for  $Av $ here I just need  to multiply A and v? so I multiplied it and got $s=\frac{2}{3}t$ ,$-2s=t$ ,$t=\frac{1}{2}s$ , $t=-\frac{1}{3}s$ (?)

Comment: all those are not equality it must be $\neq$ in each one, thus it suffices choose s and t to fulfil $Av\neq0$

Comment: thankyou so $s\neq\frac{2}{3}t$ , $-2s  \neq t$, $t  \neq \frac{1}{2}s$, $t  \neq -\frac{1}{3}s$, is this the answer? I need to find the $v$ that don't have this relation? as long as it is not produce vector $0$ ? I mean $t$ and $s$ could be anything?

Comment: for example $s=-1$ and  $t=0$ , so $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2\\0\\-3 \end {bmatrix}$ suffice?

Comment: Yes indeed, maybe there is an undeneath reason for that but at the moment I cannot see that, in any case if the aim was to find a v now you’re done since you can find infinitely many.

Comment: Try directly multiplying by the matrices!

Comment: yes I tried it wont produce zero, but is it the same if I find null space of $Av=0$ ? here if I find null space of A , $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\-4\\-2\\1\end {bmatrix}$t,  it will produce zero matrix, so it wont suffice right? so clearly v should be not linear combination of this(?), I mean why the vector that fulfill $Av\neq0$ is from $A^2$ ? so  it automatically fulfill $Av=0$ ?

Comment: The trick is to take $v$ form null($A^2$) in a general form such that $A^2v=0$ and then checking for which t,s we have $Av\neq0$. In this case we have found that all $t,s\neq 0$ work.

Comment: oh right it should suffice both condition, but how do you know that all $t,s\neq 0$ work? because it is general form(?) try one suffice all?

Answer (score 0):

No need for row reduction.

From $$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{pmatrix}$$ you can immediately see that $A^2 e_2 = 3e_1$ and $A^2e_4 = 2e_1$.

Therefore $$A^2e_2 = \frac32 A^2 e_4 \implies 0 = A^2\left(e_2 - \frac32 e_4\right) = A^2 \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac32\end{pmatrix}$$

so $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac32\end{pmatrix} \in \ker A^2$. On the other hand, we have that $$A \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac32\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2&1\\0&-1&1&-2\\2&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac32\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\frac32 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ -\frac12\end{pmatrix} \ne 0$$

so $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac32\end{pmatrix} \notin \ker A$.

Comment: thanks but how can you immediately see that $A^2 e_2 = 3e_1$ and $A^2e_4 = 2e_1$? Eigen value are 2,3 though

Comment: @fiksx The $j$-th column of any matrix $T$ is $Te_j$. Therefore the second column of $A^2$ is  precisely $A^2e_2$ and the fourth column is $A^2e_4$.

Comment: is this because you chose column that has lots of zero? is it possible that I choose $A^2e_1$? how do you know if you choose second and fourth column you will get scalar multiple of $e_1$? is this related to Eigen value too?

Comment: @fiksx Nothing to do with eigenvalues, I just took two columns which both have only the first coordinate $\ne 0$. This means that they are both scalar multiples of $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$, so in particular they are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: $A^2 \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 3 \begin{pmatrix}6\\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ or $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ ? I was so confuse about the notation $e_3$ and $e_1$ here

Comment: @fiksx Here is my entire notation: $$e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, e_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^2e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $$A^2e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 3\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 3e_1$$
$$A^2e_3 = \begin{pmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 6 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $$A^2e_4 = \begin{pmatrix}6&3&4&2\\0&0&0&0\\4&0&6&0\\2&0&3&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}= 2\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 2e_1$$

Comment: thankyou so much! if there is multiply of $e_1$ , is it mean it is automatically linear dependent? if there is column that first coordinate not equal to zero and rest is zero is $e_1$ always be an eigen vector?

Comment: sorry I'm just curious, if you have time  i would be glad if you answer my question. I just learned transformation and realized indeed transformation to standard basis produce column of matrix, then i remember your post, but in here is $e_2$ and $e_1$ considered to be same eigen vector? thankyou!!!!! $Ax= \lambda x$ ?

Comment: @fiksx No, actually $e_1$ is not an eigenvector, nor is $e_2$. It just holds that $A^2e_2$ is a scalar multiple of $e_1$.

Comment: thankyou! but is this related to transformation? and why if $A^2e_2$ a scalar multiple of $e_1$, then imply scalar multiple of each other? is it like taking $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ as basis? can you give me an idea behind this?

Comment: @fiksx What I meant before is that $A^2e_2$ and $A^2e_4$ are both scalar multiples of $e_1$. Now you can verify that $A^2e_2$ and $A^2e_4$ are scalar multiples of each other. All of this is a consequence of the fact that the columns of the matrix of a linear map in standard basis represent the action of the map on standard basis vectors.

Comment: i just learned about this, and my conclusion is, this matrix represent transformation with respect to standard basis, such as $T \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$. and $ \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_2\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_4\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$  and the rest... am i right here or verbose?

Comment: and this is the matrix representation for the transformation. so the coordinate vector $x$ is represented with respect to standard basis,  produce vector for column matrix A because $T(x)=A(x)$,  so standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ is the basis for the coordinate x. and when $T \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ imply that it is scalar multiply of one of the basis right? but can i say 3 is Eigen value? but i know that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ is different

Comment: @fiksx Precisely, the above matrix is the representation of a linear map with respect to the standard basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$. The above decomposition is also correct:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 0 \\ 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=6\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+0\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+4\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+2\cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
And, no: $T \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ does not imply that $3$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thankyou so much! But Can i say this is $[T(x)]_e$?, is this matrix also comes from another basis? And the old basis is in the column matrix(?)

Comment: @fiksx Yes, this is $[T(x)]_e$, if by that you mean the representation of the vector $A^2x$ with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: ok, thankyou so much for the helpful answer!!! :)